# XSLT - Problem with foreach and incremented attribute name

Tags: xslt

I'm using XSLT and would like to transform this:

```
<attr>
    <header name="UpdateInformation1">
        <detail name="info">blah</detail>
    </header> 
    <header name="UpdateInformation2">
        <detail name="info">blah2</detail>
    </header> 
...other headers with different names...
</attr>
```

To this:

```
<UpdateInformation>
   <info>blah</info>
</UpdateInformation>
<UpdateInformation>
   <info>blah2</info>
</UpdateInformation>
...
```

I've been trying to do this using a foreach, but I'm not having much success. Heres what I currently have, but wildcards don't work in this type of context:

*** WRONG ***

```
<xsl:for-each select="attr/header[@name='UpdateInformation*']">
    <UpdateInformation>
    <Info>
          <xsl:value-of select="detail[@name='info']"/>
        </info>
    </UpdateInformation>
</xsl:for-each>
```

*** WRONG ***

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="attr/header[starts-with(@name, 'UpdateInformation')]">
    <UpdateInformation>
        <Info>
            <xsl:value-of select="detail[@name='info']"/>
        </info>
    </UpdateInformation>
</xsl:for-each>
```

EDITED:  Corrected XPath expression per comments (below).

Comment: I actually used <xsl:for-each select="attr/header[starts-with(@name, 'UpdateInformation')]"> and that works. Thanks Drew

Comment: This won't work, as none of the `/detail` nodes has a `@name` attribute that starts with `UpdateInformation`

Comment: Ack -- good catch.

Questions here get answered so quickly... I'm usually scrambling to write a response before 7 others say what I have to say and everyone has moved on.  =P

Answer (score 2):

Doing this with the `xsl:for-each` element:

```
<xsl:for-each select="header[starts-with(@name, 'UpdateInformation')]">
 <UpdateInformation>
  <Info>
   <xsl:value-of select="detail"/>
  </info>
 </UpdateInformation>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Using a `xsl:template` would be a better way to do this in xslt, as this is the strength of it:

```
<xsl:template match="header[starts-with(@name, 'UpdateInformation')]">
 <UpdateInformation>
  <Info>
   <xsl:value-of select="detail"/>
  </info>
 </UpdateInformation>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Sorry, changed my question a bit...There would be more headers of different names. Not just UpdateInformations, and I only want to select the UpdateInformations